# Programs disappearing from auto-startup

Tags: windows-10

I have a bunch of programs that keep being disabled from starting with windows and I have no idea what's disabling them. (Might it be Windows itself?)

I ran `autoruns` and their entries are located in the Logon tab, under `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.

As far as I have been able to determine, the only difference from other autorun programs in the same category is that they are listed as `(Not verified)`.

(One such program I use is this [taskbar tweaker](https://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker). The other one is [this](https://auto-mute.com/).)

This only started happening recently. Is this some new "feature" windows introduced? Or would there likely be some other reason? Is it because they are unverified? I need help to uncover this puzzle because I don't even know where to start.

Edit: Win10 v1909, `[Version 10.0.18363.657]`

Comment: @K7AAY Win version, good point. So far I have only a sample size of 2, mentioned the second one in the post too.

Comment: I would configure Process Monitor (Microsoft/Sysinternals) with a path filter for the key in question.  You can choose to drop all the other events.  I would first perform a boot trace to see if that's where it goes missing. Then maybe try capturing the shutdown.  In either case, this will give you the process making the change and the stack of the event will give you the module making the change if needed.

Comment: @HelpingHand Tnx for the suggestions. One of the problems is they survive a few restarts, and then vanish. For ProcMon... There is an option to store events in a backing file instead of virtual memory, which means it survives the shutdown process (tried to make sure, couldn't replicate issue). But shutdown includes procmon and if it's a shutdown related process I feel we're looking at a race condition between whatever makes the change and procmon closing - not sure how to solve that. And do you mean the Windows Performance Toolkit boot trace? The one that records gigabyte-sized traces? :)

Comment: You can create a boot trace with Procmon, that would be my first test if the reg keys were going missing between shutdown and startup just because it's simple to do. You could create an etl trace of shutdown and startup with WPR/WPRUI (wpr -start Registry) for the registry io scenario.  This would give you the processes/stacks of the registry changes so it could also be an option but as you say it could be quite large.  Finally, to get a more specific log fo specific reg changes, you could write a service that uses regnotifychangekeyvalue to record changes to a given key to a log.